# VBA Select Case is multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, with-statement, select-case

I have the following piece of code and would like to modify it a bit. Basically with every `case is` i want to check a secondary criteria. For example `Case is = "Lottery"` i want to add on `AND range("SalesChannel").value = "SMB"`. i would then like to replicate that for every case is using a different value (not SMB). can this be done?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With LoginPassword.TextBox1.Value
Select Case Me.TextBox1.Value
    Case Is = "Lottery"
        LoginPassword.Hide
        SMB_Login
        CalculateFinancials
    Case Is = "Charity"
        LoginPassword.Hide
        DCS_Login
        CalculateFinancials
    Case Is = "Curfew"
        LoginPassword.Hide
        Campaign_Login
        CalculateFinancials
    Case Is = "Europe"
        LoginPassword.Hide
        Eureka_Login
        CalculateFinancials
    Case Is = "Promo"
        LoginPassword.Hide
        Promo_Login
        CalculateFinancials
    Case Is = "Sundew"
        LoginPassword.Hide
        Loyalty_Login
        CalculateFinancials
    Case Is = "Casino"
        LoginPassword.Hide
        MobilePricing.Hide
        Range("Network").ClearContents
    Case Is = "RedDevil"
        HardwareUpdateYesNo
    Case Is = "Provision"
        LoginPassword.Hide
        MobilePricing.Hide
        ProvisioningView
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Password Incorrect!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Login Failed!"
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox1.SetFocus
End Select
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample Select Case with multiple criteria:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Select Case True        
        Case 1 = 1 And True 
            Debug.Print 1
        Case True And 2 = 5
            Debug.Print 2
        Case True And 5 = 5 And 6 = 7
            Debug.Print 3
    End Select

End Sub
```

In your case you should simply write your conditions instead of `1=1` or `True`. Like this: `Case Me.TextBox1.Value = "Lottery" and range("SalesChannel").value = "SMB"` But leave `Select Case True` on the top.